# Should there be a 'husbandry' tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I recently asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158067) about how many people would be required to care for a particular menagerie. It's tagged [farming](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/farming) and [zoology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology), which could be worse, but neither tag quite fits the topic, which is caring for animals, i.e. [husbandry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_husbandry). (Farming usually refers to plants, and zoology a) is a much broader field and b) is not usually associated with *domestic* animals.)

I wonder if there should be a (separate) tag for this? (It clearly meets the "expert" test...)

Answer (score 3):

The following is the description of the [zoology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology) tag:

> For questions relating to the study or analysis of animals, animal husbandry, or the discussion of animal behavior and evolution.

---

Please use [zoology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoology) for all husbandry-related questions.

Comment: ...but that's like saying we shouldn't have [tag:xenobiology] because we have [tag:biology]. You are arguing, then, that AH is "too niche" or something along those lines?

Comment: @Matthew Yes. Personally I think [tag:xenobiology] should be made into a synonym of [tag:biology]